# Bootstrap material design input tag change default teal color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, colors, material-design

Hi Guys Im trying to change the default color of the Bootstrap material design input tag green color to various different colors, I already saw a solution here(https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/issues/384) but it not seems to work, I googled it many possible ways but didn't get the solution, I don't know what Im missing here, below is my sample code, with the all necessary files I tried. All dependent files are taken form officials sites only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Material Design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-material-design.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ripples.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="material.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ripples.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.material.init()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please review this and suggest me if I did any mistake or if i missed anything please let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that you need to overwrite `material styles`.

add **css**

```
.form-group.is-focused .form-control{
      background-image: linear-gradient(#c22, #c11), linear-gradient(#a43, #a11);
}
```

If you want to give a `border` by default (not-focused situation)

```
.form-control, .form-group .form-control{
   background-image: linear-gradient(#c22, #c11), linear-gradient(#a43, #a11); 
}
```

To change the color of label:

```
 .form-group.is-focused label .form-group.is-focused label.control-label{
    color: blue; // any color that you want
}
```

Comment: Ya its works fine as my exception, thanks for your kind reply, but in case if I have a validation(required), so it must have to show in red color, in this case what ever color we gave ,same color reflects for validation also

'<div class="form-group label-floating has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    <span class="form-control-feedback" id="name1"></span>
</div>' .

Comment: 1 sec. lemme check

Comment: @AjayKumar Can you please send any link of demo that shows this form validation?

Comment: Please refer this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yzfvl80oagrna2/bmd.zip?dl=0 for the files which I have tried with form validation

Comment: @AjayKumar I got the issue .. remove `!important` from the code for working with errors. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much its working, how about the label color it remains that teal color itself, any way to change that to input tag color

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with less:

http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/PzgWkm

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
@input-success: rgba(0,32,132,0.8);
@input-underline-color: rgba(123,321,312,0.8);

.form-group.is-focused .form-control {
    background-image: linear-gradient(@input-success, @input-success), linear-gradient(@input-underline-color, @input-underline-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using MDBOOSTRAP then this is the solution.
for the input try this:

```
input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 black;
}
```

and for the label :

```
input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly])+label{
  color: black;
}
```